# Cassandra & Python Driver Issue

Tags: python, cassandra

I am getting this issue with my Cassandra, please help me resolve this issue. I am using the latest version of the cassandra_driver and python 3.10.5

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002):
 tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.cpython-310-darwin.so' (not a mach-o file)
```

Comment: Sorry for the badly formatted original question. This is my first time posting a question, so thanks for helping me edit it 

Comment: Are you on a Mac M1?  Also, what output do you see when you run this: `python -c 'import cassandra; print ("cassandra driver version == " + cassandra.__version__)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue, what happened was I was using a version of python that wasn't supported by the Cassandra driver. Only python 2.7,3.5,3.6,3.7 and 3.8 work.

Comment: 3.9 works as well